# Setting up lintnode

Tags: node.js, emacs, elisp, npm

So, I'm trying to set up lintnode to work with emacs, and it seems like it installs fine. I don't get an error in the buffer or anything when I start up.

However, when I go to write some JS I don't get any of the functionality. So I check npm to see if all the node packages are up to date, they aren't, but even after I do 'npm update' and get 200 responses the versions are still unchanged. I'm running Xubuntu for a little background info.

Here's a copy of my emacs init file to check out if you think that could be the issue.

Here's a paste bin of it if this is too messy. [Emacs Init](http://pastebin.com/gMmSvNX8)

```lisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/auto-complete-1.3.1")
;Load the default configuration
(require 'auto-complete-config)
;Make sure we can find the dictionaries
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/auto-complete-1.3.1/dict")
;Use dictionaries by default
(setq-default ac-sources (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-dictionary))
(global-auto-complete-mode t)
;Start auto completion after two characters of a word
(setq ac-auto-start 2)
; case sensitivity is important when finding matches
(setq ac-ignore-case nil)

(add-hook 'js-mode-hook'
  (lambda ()
    ;;Scan the file for nested code blocks
    (imenu-add-menubar-index)
    ;;Activate folding mode
    (hs-minor-mode t)
    )
)

;;Yasnipped: Auto-codesnippet manager
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet")
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)

;;Lintnode
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/lintnode")
(require 'flymake-jslint)
(add-hook 'javascript-mode-hook
  (lambda () (flymake-mode t)))
(custom-set-variables
  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(lintnode-autostart t))
(custom-set-faces
  ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

;;Flymake-the nice minibuffer cursor linked message
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/flymake")
(require 'flymake-cursor)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra quote at the end of `js-mode-hook`.
And the source of the problem might be that you later use `javascript-mode-hook` which doesn't exist AFAIK (`javascript-mode` is an alias to `js-mode` so the hook is called `js-mode-hook`).

Comment: No luck on that unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

This has the correct instructinos for installing JSLint with lintnode.
http://emacswiki.org/emacs/FlymakeJavaScript